# How do I handle promise rejection in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have some fairly simple code, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
  try {
    service.cache.client = await initCache();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

and

```
const initCache = async () => {
  const options = {
    url: my_URL,
    port: my_PORT + 4
  };

  const client = await getClient(options);

  client.on('connect', (a, b) => {
    logger.info(
      `Successfully connected:  ${my_URL}:${my_PORT}`
    );
    client.connect = true;
  });

  client.on('error', (err) => Promise.reject());

  return client;
};
```

EDIT:  I should add that in my example above, `my_URL` is a bogus URL that will never connect.  I'm trying to write some code so the app uses alternate methods when the chache client is unavailable.

No matter what I do, I cannot escape Unhandled Rejection warnings.  The code above results in `error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise`.  If I pass a new error to `Promise.reject`, I get the same thing.  If I throw my own error in the catch block, I still get `error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise`.  What do I have to do to actually handle this rejection?

EDIT:  if I change `client.on` to `client.on('error', (err) => new Error(err));`, the Unhandled Promise message goes away. But I'm unable to catch this error in the catch block; a simple `console.log` isn't happening.

Comment: You're not rejecting the promise that is returned from `initiCache`. You're just creating a new rejected promise inside the `error` callback that is handled nowhere.

Comment: What is `getClient`? Which library are you using, what does it return, when does the promise fulfill? Do you actually need to wait for the connection to occur?

Comment: If the function provided as a callback to `EventEmitter.prototype.on` returns a value, that value will be ignored - so you can see that your `Promise.reject()` has no significance!

Answer (score 0):

When using callbacks with promises you have to do a little bit of work to make them work nice together. If I understand your intention you want to wait for the client to connect to return the promise, and in case of the event `error` you want to throw an error.

You have to return a new Promise like so:

```
const initCache = async () => {
  const options = {
    url: my_URL,
    port: my_PORT + 4,
  };

  const client = await getClient(options);

  return new Promise((success, reject) => {
    client.on("connect", (a, b) => {
      logger.info(`Successfully connected:  ${my_URL}:${my_PORT}`);
      client.connect = true;
      success(client);
    });

    client.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
  });
};
```